# Run a function after user has verified email in Meteor using ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3?

Tags: meteor

I've got `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` installed. When the user has verified their email, I want Meteor to create them as a Stripe Customer.

*/client/global_client_functions.js*

```
Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink(function(){
    console.log("verification link clicked!");
    alert(Meteor.user()._id);
    Meteor.call("createStripeCustomer", Meteor.user()._id)
});
```

`Meteor.call("createStripeCustomer", Meteor.user()._id)` works fine and dandy when I pass in a userId.

But `Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink` never seems to get called and I also don't get the error "onEmailVerificationLink can only be called once".

Am I using `Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink` correctly? I don't want to roll my own account ui, so I'd like to stick with using the `accounts-ui` package.

Comment: best option would be overriding the verification route and use `Accounts.verifyEmail` so in the callback you can call this method. If interseted I can provide snippet in answer.

Comment: Yeah, a snippet would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Iron router

this is the default link that meteor generates

```
this.route('verify-emailHash',{
    controller: 'AccountController',
    path: '/#/verify-email/:token',
    action: 'verifyEmail'
})

//I changed my verification link like below
this.route('verify-email',{
    controller: 'AccountController',
    path: '/verify-email/:token',
    action: 'verifyEmail'
})

AccountController = RouteController.extend({
    verifyEmail: function () {
        Accounts.verifyEmail(this.params.token, function () {
            toastr.success("Email verified");
            alert(Meteor.user()._id);
            Meteor.call("createStripeCustomer", Meteor.user()._id)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: looks like the package you're using already using that function here: https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/de29b1f7855395157db2869c0b018779d7eb6a94/login_buttons_dialogs.js#L24 either you need to clone the package and change the code there or comment that code if you want to continue with this solution

Comment: I see. That's too bad. Would it be a really bad idea to have `.observe` running on the `Meteor.users` query and anytime it detects that `email[0].verified` has been changed to true to run my intended function?

Comment: Yes I feel that is unncessary load on the server all the time, best option for me would be this